# updating javascript variable after .NET doPostBack fires

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to update a javascript variable whenever my vb.net page fires a "doPostBack" event which causes a .net session variable to update.

I tried adding this but it doesn't work.

```
<script>

    var mySessionVariable = '<%= Session("monsterID")%>';

    addToPostBack = function (func) {
        var old__doPostBack = __doPostBack;
        if (typeof __doPostBack != 'function') {
            __doPostBack = func;
        } else {
            __doPostBack = function (t, a) {
                if (func(t, a)) old__doPostBack(t, a);
            }
        }
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {

         addToPostBack(function (t, a) {
             mySessionVariable = '<%= Session("monsterID")%>';
         });

         console.log("mySessionVariable: ", mySessionVariable);
   });

</script>
```

Even though the Session variable changes on the vb.net side after firing an event that does a "doPostBack", it remains the same both before and after the postback on the client side side.

```
MonsterVar1
MonsterVar1
```

Is there anyway to get this to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't make more sense to have a Hidden Field instead of grabbing something from the session to make it work with JS on the page:

```
 <asp:HiddenField id="HiddenField1" runat=Server />
```

JS

```
//document.getElementById('<%= HiddenField1.ClientID%>');

var value = document.getElementById("<%= Hiddenfield1.ClientID %>").value
```

Comment: Wouldn't that require a form?  I'm just using an update panel.  Thanks!

Comment: As far as I recall you need a form to use an update panel but of course there are some new variation of it that may not require it but the one from MS required it

Comment: Yeah I think you are right...I just 'viewed source' and I see a form with an id of 'aspnetForm'. So .net must be adding it behind the scenes.

Comment: but still, I need the javascript to read the variable and I don't see how I could do that even with a hiddenfield.

Comment: `'<%= HiddenField1.ClientID%>'` that gets you the hidden field

Comment: `document.getElementById("<%= Hiddenfield1.ClientID %>").value`